# Error with "unsupported operand type" when converting feet to inches

Tags: python, computer-science

I am working on a homework problem, and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users//Dropbox/Homework 3 - 2.py", line 15, in <module>
    conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(get_feet)   
File "/Users//Dropbox/Homework 3 - 2.py", line 4, in convert_feet_to_inches
    calculate_conversion = feet*12 TypeError: 
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
```

Here is my code. I'm trying to convert feet to inches:

```
def convert_feet_to_inches(feet):
    calculate_conversion = feet*12
    return calculate_conversion

def get_feet():
    ask_for_feet = float(input("Please enter number of feet for conversion "))
    return ask_for_feet

def printing_answer():
    print (convert_feet_to_inches)

asking_for_feet = get_feet()
conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(get_feet)
print_answer(printing_answer)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to pass `asking_for_feet` to `convert_feet_to_inches` instead of the function `get_feet` in this line:

```
conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(get_feet)
```

So that should be:

```
conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(asking_for_feet)
```

Comment: you are right i fixed that part, and i fixed the last line into print_answer = (printing_answer), but now nothing comes out, i do not get an error, i simply input and the program ends, i dont see why it doesnt do the multiplication

Comment: @user2803150 In your `printing_answer` function, use return and not print.

Comment: def printing_answer():
    return (convert_feet_to_inches)

this is the edit i made, i still do not receive an output, thank you for all your help, i think ill just think on it

Answer (score 0):

The error was because `get_feet()` is a function and you passed it to `convert_feet_to_inches()` which is taking the argument you pass it and multiplying it by 12. You can't multiply a function by an int so that is what the error was saying. I think what you meant to do was to pass `asking_for_feet`. So change

```
conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(get_feet)
```

to

```
conversion = convert_feet_to_inches(asking_for_feet)
```

After that, you have

```
print_answer(printing_answer)
```

The function `print_answer` was not defined yet so change:

```
def printing_answer():
    print (convert_feet_to_inches)
```

to

```
def print_answer(answer):
    print (answer)
```

Then you final line of code would be:

```
print_answer(conversion)
```